# Python convert specific dataframe columns to integer

Tags: python, dataframe, integer, type-conversion

I have a dataframe of 8 columns and I would like to convert last six columns to integer. The dataframe contains also NaN values and I don't want to remove them.

[image]

```
      a      b    c     d     e     f     g    h
0   john     1   NaN   2.0    2.0  42.0  3.0  NaN
1   david    2  28.0  52.0   15.0  NaN   2.0  NaN
2   kevin    3   1.0   NaN   1.0   10.0  1.0  5.0
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if the floating values already present in the columns can be restricted within an interval? Say [0,100]?

Comment: yes this is simple and soon you got an answer :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to MaxU I'm adding this option with nan = -1:

> Reason: nan values are float values and can't coexist with integers.
>   So either nan values and floats or the option to think of -1 as nan

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': {0: 'john', 1: 'david', 2: 'kevin'},
 'b': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'c': {0: np.nan, 1: 28.0, 2: 1.0},
 'd': {0: 2.0, 1: 52.0, 2: np.nan},
 'e': {0: 2.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 1.0},
 'f': {0: 42.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 10.0},
 'g': {0: 3.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0},
 'h': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: 5.0}})

df.iloc[:, -6:] = df.iloc[:, -6:].fillna(-1)
df.iloc[:, -6:] = df.iloc[:, -6:].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')

df

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
0   john    1   -1  2   2   42  3   -1
1   david   2   28  52  15  -1  2   -1
2   kevin   3   1   -1  1   10  1   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [@AntonvBR for the `downcast='integer'` hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618781/python-convert-specific-dataframe-columns-to-integer/46618808#comment80188772_46618808):

```
In [29]: df.iloc[:, -6:] = df.iloc[:, -6:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='integer')

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
       a  b     c     d   e     f  g    h
0   john  1   NaN   2.0   2  42.0  3  NaN
1  david  2  28.0  52.0  15   NaN  2  NaN
2  kevin  3   1.0   NaN   1  10.0  1  5.0

In [31]: df.dtypes
Out[31]:
a     object
b      int64
c    float64
d    float64
e       int8
f    float64
g       int8
h    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey! It's impossible to even start thinking of a solution before some of you guys type something. But he wants **integers.** downcast='integer'?

Comment: Yes, I need integer..this converts to float :) @AntonvBR

Comment: @Giada, integer column(s) can't have NaN's, so you either need to replace NaN's with some integer value or to live with floats...

Comment: @MaxU Using downcast='integer' the g column I get is integer, yours is float. I used **df.iloc[:, -6:] = df.iloc[:, -6:].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')**

Comment: @AntonvBR, yes, my bad, sorry! It's fixed now